# bupaR - changing the metric the process map displays?

Tags: r, logging

I've gone through their documentation ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/processmapR/processmapR.pdf) & [here](https://www.bupar.net/processmaps.html#introduction)), but I don't see a simple way to tweak this.  For instance if I wanted the lines to show time spent in minutes and the bubbles to show the distinct # of cases that appeared there instead of absolute/relative frequency - ex: when looking at incident case data.

Do I have to render the process map myself via DiagrammeR?  I was trying to find some a similar example in DiagrammeR but I couldn't find much.

Any tips / good examples I could reference?  I suppose its because this is quite new.  [I did find this older article](http://www.dataminingapps.com/2017/11/a-process-mining-tour-in-r/) but I wasn't sure how to connect the dots.  Is it worth continuing my analysis in bupaR or should I leverage a different process map generating library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't possible so far, but it is now due to a recent change on the Github [repo](https://github.com/bupaverse/processmapR). You can now have frequencies on nodes and times on arrow (or vice versa).

What you do is, first install the github version of the package:

```r
devtools::install_github("gertjanssenswillen/processmapr")
```

then, use the new `type_edges` and `type_nodes` arguments, in the same way as you would use the *type argument* before.

```r
data %>% process_map(type_nodes = frequency(value = "absolute_case"), type_edges = performance(FUN = mean, units = "min"))
```

Comment: So cool!  But it keeps saying I have unused arguments in my frequency label.  Seems like its still using the old processR.  Does it matter i'm still using R 3.3.3?  Error in frequency(type = "absolute_case", type_edges = performances(FUN = mean,  : 
  unused arguments (type = "absolute_case", type_edges = performances(FUN = mean, units = "min"))

Comment: Also looks like the process map is backwards now.  It shows bubbles Start to End from top to bottom but the data looks like its going from end to start.  This also appeared even just doing something simple like data.map <- data %>%
  filter_trace_frequency(perc = 0.8) %>%
  process_map(type = frequency("absolute"))

Comment: My fault, there were some typos in the code: 

data %>% process_map(type_nodes = frequency(value = "absolute_case"), type_edges = performance(FUN = mean, units = "min"))

Does this still give the map backwards?

Comment: Just for a sanity check I uninstalled the packages and re-installed the official bupaR & processmapR from cran.  The map looks correct now.  So it does seem to have something to do when change the processmapR package.  There aren't any other dependant packages I am leaving out is there?  Maybe I need to download the whole bupaR set of packages from your git?

Comment: The minute I execute devtools::install_github("gertjanssenswillen/processmapr", dependencies=TRUE), I end up with the map essentially upside down (start is still on top and end on bottom)  Along with the following error:

Comment: Error in data.frame(id = 1:n, from = from, to = to, rel = rel, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 0
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding factor and character vector, coercing into character vector
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: I get an error: "Error in xy.coords: x is a list, but has no components x and y.